# Display several videos in MediaElement

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xaml

Via an XML file, I have to get a title, the link of a video and a date for display on WindowsPhone 8.
I browse the file with the following code:

```
 foreach (var item in xElement.Elements("channel").Elements("item"))
            {
                var feed = new Feed
                    {
                        Link = item.Element("description").Value,
                        PubDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Title = item.Element("title").Value
                    };
                Results.Items.Add(feed);
            }
```

This code retrieves the values ​​correctly. I use the binding to link the two :

```
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0">
            <ItemsControl Name="Results"  >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />

                            <MediaElement Name="Media"
                                          Source="{Binding Path=Link}" 
                                          Stretch="Fill"
                                          AutoPlay="True" />

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PubDate}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is that only two videos are displayed (and not always the same). I don't know where the error is it, because all the data is retrieved, including links to my videos.
I would also add controls to the MediaElement such as : Play, Stop,... But I don't know where to place the code.

I'm sorry for my English ! I'm French. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I remember reading on MSDN that the number of active MediaElement that are fully supported on Windows Phone is one (this was either 7.0 or 7.1 mind you). I can no longer find this reference on MSDN, but if you search the web, you'll find similar assertions (though with no MSDN quotes or whatever).

Try having just the one and see if it works as you expect, and then try to go up to two.

Comment: There are just two that are displayed. No more.